# Lyx not opening, windows 10

Tags: lyx, windows

Im having a strange problem. I have used lyx always and last time I used it was a few days ago.

Today my computer for strange reasons starting saying it was completely full (0 byte free!). Opened lyx to test a math equation layout, couldnt save document, couldnt display pdf. I thought it might be related to the disk space issue, so I restarted my computer, and now I had 11 GB free, as I should have (strange...).

Lyx now wouldnt open at all! No errors, just nothing. Ive tried to reinstall, same problem. Also if I reinstall to a different folder.

Im completely at a loss here, and cannot find similar problems and solutions out there. Did anyone try something similar? Im desparate since I have several papers and reports due this week!

Edit: more information:  I'm using the newest LyX 2.1.4 and have Miktex 2.9 installed. I have TeXWorks installed as well, and it works and compiles, so its not a Miktex issue.

Comment: Did you made backups which are safe somewhere else?

Comment: I have backups of my LyX documents, yes. Or I mean, they were not corrupted, so I just have them as I used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work again now. I installed LyX directly under C:\  instead of in Program Files ,  or in Program Files (x86), as it had originally been.

I don't know why this works or why the other one didn't since I have used it for years in that location.

Anyway, working now. Hope someone else benefits from this.